# In Postgresql Order Query Results by int[] Used in Query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, psql

I want to query a table using a similar query to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=ANY(ARRAY[454, 345, 987, 247]) ORDER BY ?;
```

Is there a way to replace the ? in ORDER BY with something that will order rows by the index order of the integers in ARRAY[454, 345, 987, 247]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;

SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id=ANY(ARRAY[454, 345, 987, 247])
ORDER BY idx(ARRAY[454, 345, 987, 247], id);
```

Only works for integer array though. For others you'll have to write your own `idx` (and it won't be fast).

See [intarray](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html).

I think that in 9.4 this can be done faster using `UNNEST(...) WITH ORDINALITY`.